# How can I automate the assignment of GTIN codes to match SKUs during Google Merchant Center import from Magento feed?

Tags: magento, magento2.4, google-merchant-center

I connected Google Merchant Center to my Magento feed, and when using website crawl, the products import successfully but lack GTIN codes. This forces me to manually edit each product in Google Merchant Center. Is there a way to automate the assignment of GTIN codes to match SKUs during the import?